# Loop through array and replace value on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

My array and pseudo code are as follows. I do need help with replacing values with stirng on condition. I tried below but can't move on.

```
var = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];

for (var i = 0; i < arR.length; i++) {
    if (arR.includes >= 5000) {
        (‘senior’);
    } else if (arR.includes >= 2000) {
        console.log(‘mid’);
    } else {
        (‘junior’);
    }
}
```

Expected result: `var = [senior, mid, mid, junior];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let array = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];

let TransformedArray = array.map(item=>item>=5000 ? 'senior' : item>=2000 ? 'mid' : 'junior');

console.log(TransformedArray);
```

Comment: I understand correctly that `item=>item` is arrow function?

Comment: Yes it is. When there is one line there's no need (illegal) to use ```return``` keyword.

Comment: Do you have an article that explains arrow function in detail? They are quite bugging me to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Array.map() and use any conditional operator to filter the result im using ternary here.

```js
    var someArray = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];


    var anotherArray = someArray.map(function (rank) {
      return rank >= 5000 ? 'senior' : rank >= 2000 ? 'mid' : 'junior';
    });

    console.log(anotherArray);
```

if you need it this way for easy understanding of if else and for each

```js
var someArray = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];

var newArray = [];

someArray.forEach(function (rank) {
    if (rank >= 5000) {
        newArray.push('senior');
    } else if (rank >= 2000) {
        newArray.push('mid');
    } else {
        newArray.push('junior');
    }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];

function converter(item) {
  return item >= 5000 && 'senior' || item >= 2000 && 'mid' || item >= 0 && 'junior';
}

var newArray = array.map(converter)
console.log(newArray);
```

The function returns false if an element is not a number (or smaller than 0). If you want to change that, you should cover the return with an if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace that element in the array, also iterate through the actual elements in your for-loop instead of checking if the value exists

```
var arR = [5000, 2000, 4030, 1100];

for (var i = 0; i < arR.length; i++) {
    if (arR[i] >= 5000) {
        arR[i] = "senior";
    } else if (arR[i] >= 2000) {
        arR[i] = "mid"
    } else {
        arR[i] = "junior"
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is checking each value, and if it satisfies a condition, then change it to the string it needs to be